# How to populate a source file having date format 'mm/dd/yyyy' to a target table column having date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' in teradata fatsload script

Tags: sql-server, unix, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

How to populate a source file having date format 'mm/dd/yyyy' to a target table column having date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' in teradata fastload script

Comment: If its a date, you should have a `date` column, which has no format.

Comment: Date and Time columns have no formats, so getting the format "right" in the destination is a moot point. For the source value, is this a text file? If you're American, then a text string in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` will be consumed as such. If not, one method would be to import to a staging table, and then `CONVERT` the value with a style code.

Comment: Apply a format in Insert: `sourcecolumn (date, format 'mm/dd/yyyy')`